# When running a command in Intellij, how do I make filenames clickable in the output?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea

I have a grunt task that I've configured in IntelliJ 11 (sadly can't upgrade to 12 yet). The output of the command contains filenames when there is a problem. I've basically followed the configuration example I saw in the Karma setup video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI (instructions start at 7:39 but the feature is demonstrated at 10:40).

I've created a new Node.js run configuration, put in the correct path to node, changed the path to the file to be grunt and then listed the Application parameters to be what they should. It runs fine.

The output of my grunt task spits out filenames with absolute paths followed by a colon and a line number, just like in that example. I'm curious why my files aren't clickable though.

I'd expect the path in the last line of this to be clickable:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.1 (Mac OS X) CookiesTests test set, get, and delete cookie FAILED
    AssertError: expected "js-test-value" not to be equal to "js-test-value"
            at /Users/matt/Projects/task-core/test/cookies.jstd:17
```

And it should open the file test/cookies.jstd to line 17.

Is there an opportunity to configure IntelliJ so that it recognizes the output as having file names so that it can activate links?

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/add-edit-filter.html.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder, I'm not using an external tool in this case primarily because this is a run configuration for just this project. I'm actually using a Node.js run configuration provided by the Node.js plugin. Is there a way to configure an external tool task for specific projects?